# clickale table llayout in android

Tags: android, tablelayout

In my application i have a  table layout with 4 rows.In 1 row i displayed 2 data with some space in-between  them which will look like having 2 columns.Now what i want is i have to start different intent by clicking this data.When i click 1st column it should start an intent and by clicking 2nd should start another intent.Is it possible to define region in table layout.Please help me.

Here is my table layout code:

```
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:paddingTop="4dip"
     android:paddingBottom="6dip"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">    
<TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/tablelayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:paddingRight="2dip"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1">

    <TableRow  >
 <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Income">
     </TextView>      

        <TextView             
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Expense" android:layout_marginLeft="-150dp">
     </TextView>                     

    </TableRow>    
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/line1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FF909090"
                android:padding="2dip" />
        </TableRow>


    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tablerowhouse"   android:layout_marginTop="30px">
 <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Household:" >
     </TextView>            
        <TextView             
            android:id="@+id/text50" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Household:" android:layout_marginLeft="-250dp" >
     </TextView>   

          <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Household:" android:layout_marginLeft="-150dp" >
     </TextView>            
        <TextView             
            android:id="@+id/text53" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Household:" android:layout_marginLeft="-70dp" >
     </TextView>    

    </TableRow>



        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/line1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FF909090"
                android:padding="2dip" />
        </TableRow>


 <TableRow  android:layout_marginTop="40px">
 <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Travel:" android:layout_span="3">
     </TextView>     
      <TextView
           android:id="@+id/text51"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Travel" android:layout_marginLeft="-250dp">
     </TextView>     

           <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Travel:" android:layout_marginLeft="-150dp" >
     </TextView>            
        <TextView             
            android:id="@+id/text54" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Travel:" android:layout_marginLeft="-70dp">
     </TextView>    
 </TableRow>


     <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/line1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FF909090"
                android:padding="2dip" />
        </TableRow>


     <TableRow  android:layout_marginTop="40px">
 <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Education:" android:layout_span="4">
     </TextView>     
      <TextView
           android:id="@+id/text52"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Education" android:layout_marginLeft="-250dp">
     </TextView>  

           <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Education:" android:layout_marginLeft="-150dp" >
     </TextView>            
        <TextView             
            android:id="@+id/text55" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Education:"  android:layout_marginLeft="-70dp">
     </TextView>    
 </TableRow>


          <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/line1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FF909090"
                android:padding="2dip" />
        </TableRow>


          <TableRow  android:layout_marginTop="40px">
 <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Total:" android:layout_span="5">
     </TextView>     
      <TextView
           android:id="@+id/totincome" 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Total" android:layout_marginLeft="-250dp">
     </TextView>  

           <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Total:" android:layout_marginLeft="-150dp" >
     </TextView>            
        <TextView             
            android:id="@+id/totexpense" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Total:"  android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp">
     </TextView>    
 </TableRow>

               <TableRow  android:layout_marginTop="40px">
 <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Balance:" android:layout_span="6"  android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" >
     </TextView>     
      <TextView
           android:id="@+id/balance"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="balance" android:layout_marginLeft="-150dp" >
     </TextView>  


 </TableRow>



</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you need to use setOnClickListener for each row

Comment: Thanks imran khan.Row is clickable ..Bur i need is in a single row,if i touch 1 part it should start an intent and touching another part that is above half the  screen it should start another intent..

Comment: yes it is possible to give click events for each row in the table layout.we donot need to define region it will take whole row

Comment: i made row clickable,its working fine.But i want is inside 1 row itself i want 2 clicks. is it possible.

Comment: than assign click events to individuals

Comment: Please give an idea how to do that..I am wondering for that....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add click event to individual text after initializing like

```
 Text1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


  Intent  i = new Intent(this, MainMenu.class);
        startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```